object-fit: contain breaks responsive image srcset
I have a simple scenario, where I have the left side of the screen a static image, and the right one is scrollable based on content. Left side width depends on screen size. Something like "if bigger than 1600: 50%; if between 800 and 1600 - 300px; if lower - 200px" (an example).
I want to use an image along with a srcset, so that I can get the browser swapping images for me. The thing is - if I get at 1500, the image should be only 300px wide, but I'm using the full blown 4k one. The height of the image is always 100vh (entire screen).
I'm using object-fit: cover on the image, which works great (positioning it just right, as it would with background-image).
I've applied the appropriate sizes with a srcset.

Problem: combining object-fit: cover with a srcset and sizes leads to browser not being able to properly load the corresponding image. Here's a live example of the issue (as someone else was trying to make it work, but it actually doesn't):
https://roelfjan.github.io/object-fit-cover/
Check out the second example: "Image with responsive behaviour (srcset attribute)". You can easily see that the image has a few options for display:
<img src="example-images/example2@400x267.jpg"
  srcset="example-images/example2@2400x1600.jpg 2400w,
    example-images/example2@1200x800.jpg 1200w,
    example-images/example2@800x533.jpg 800w,
    example-images/example2@400x267.jpg 400w"
  sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1170px,
    (min-width: 992px) 970px,
    (min-width: 768px) 750px,
    100vw"
  alt="Example 2" />

One would suggest, that if the screen is at 800px, the image would be rendered as 750px one, so he should get the 800px wide one? Well if you check the network tab (and you'd also see it visible as sizes are in the center of the image) - you will see the initial image displayed is 1200x800 (at 500px screen). The only time this changes, is at around 680px, when the twice as big one (2400x1600) is loaded and displayed. All of that leads me to believe there's something pretty wrong there. Or what am I missing? Tested both on Chrome and FF.

Now my scenario might be a bit easier, as of now I have only horizontal images, and my height is always 100vh. Which means I might calculate (even in CSS) the required width of the image that is about to be displayed. I'm saying all of that as I'd be happy to any hack you might know :)

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>). Include the actual images or ones that have identical properties (eg. width, height, etc.)

@zer00ne in my text, there's a link for reproduction, which is way better than me pasting here a screen or two of boilerplate code :)

The problem with external links is that they die - rendering the question useless for future readers.
